# CSS stylesheet doesn't work in express app

Tags: css, express

In my app.js I have
`` app.use(express.static(`public`)); ``
and in my HTML I've got
`` <link rel = `stylesheet` href = `css/styles.css`/> ``
None of the css from the stylesheet is working. What can be done?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = `en` dir = `ltr`>
<head>
  <meta charset = `utf-8` />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/51479f1cdc.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel = `stylesheet` href = `css/styles.css`/>
  <title>Starting Files</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class = `container full-height-container`>
    <div class = `home-container`>
      <i class = `fas fa-key fa-6x`></i>

      <h1 class = `display-3 heading`>Secrets</h1>

      <p class = `lead`>
        Don't keep your secrets, share them anonymously.
      </p>
      <hr/>

      <div class = `button-container`>
        <a class = `btn btn-primary btn-lg` href = `/register` role = `button`>Register</a>
        <a class = `btn btn-dark btn-lg` href = `/login` role = `button`>Log in</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The public folder contains a folder named css. Inside css there is a single file styles.css.

Comment: Can I see your index.html and your public folder?

Comment: please check that your css is public directory. Folder structure should be ```-Public --/css/style.css```

Comment: Hai Huynh Ngoc, I've added the information you've requested. Thanks.

Comment: I need see your index.html

Comment: My index.html is posted right under the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styles.css did not work because of the backticks used in `` <link rel = `stylesheet` href = `css/styles.css`/> `` instead of quotation marks. Backticks work in JavaScript but do not work in HTML.